# Iterating through loop on laravel 4 (update)

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-4

Good Day,

Why is it that im getting an error when I iterate loop in laravel 4 here is my code on my controller:

When I tried to:

```
$input = Input::get('product');
echo "<pre>";
dd($input);
```

i get the correct value which is:

```
array(3) {
[""]=>
array(1) {
["name"]=>
string(1) "6"
 }
[0]=>
array(5) {
  ["description"]=>
  string(64) "default description for test item no. 1.                        "
  ["itemId"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["poContentId"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["price"]=>
  string(2) "60"
  }
[1]=>
array(5) {
  ["description"]=>
   string(64) "default description for test item no. 2.                        "
  ["itemId"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["poContentId"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["price"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

but when I tried to iterate through loop here is my code:

```
foreach ( $input as $v ) {
  dd($v['poContentId']);
}
```

i get `Undefined index: poContentId` error..

Im trying to do a batch update here, can you please take a look at my code, I dont know what im missing here. Thank your for your guide!

Comment: The first element in your array does not have a `poContentId` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is not well constructed. You have 3 index : `""`, `0` and `1`. In your first index, you have just a small array only with a `name` index and no `poContentId`, that's why you get an error.

In your form you have to write inputs like that :

```
<input name="name"/>

<input name="items[0][description]"/>
<input name="items[0][itemId]"/>
<input name="items[0][description]"/>
<input name="items[0][quantity]"/>
<input name="items[0][poContentId]"/>
<input name="items[0][price]"/>

<input name="items[1][description]"/>
<input name="items[1][itemId]"/>
<input name="items[1][description]"/>
<input name="items[1][quantity]"/>
<input name="items[1][poContentId]"/>
<input name="items[1][price]"/>
```

Of course, you can use the Laravel Form class.

Like that you will be able to iterate only over the items :

```
$items = Input::get('items');
foreach ( $items as $v ) {
    dd($v['poContentId']);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Already figured it out! I rendered `<input name="items[{{$count}}][name] />` instead of `<input name="items[0][name]"/>` been burning my head for hours because of this >< if you could have only answered earlier you could have saved me hours!! anyway thank you Very much for the  willingnes to help!